# unable to pass recordtypeid in the lightning component create event

Tags: lightning-aura-components

unable to pass recordtypeid in the lightning component create event

```
createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Task",
        "recordTypeId" : component.get(v.Task.recortypeid)
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

---

### Updates

```
createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Task",
        "recordTypeId" : component.get("v.Task.recortypeid")
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

I am getting the following error

> Task Record Type ID: This value isn't valid for the user:

Answer (score 3):

I think `component.get(v.Task.recortypeid)` should be `component.get("v.Task.recortypeid")`

```
createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Task",
        "recordTypeId" : component.get("v.Task.recortypeid")
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that wont work. Did anyone used recordTypeId while creating task/event/any object? I am getting the following error

Comment: @chaith what error?

Comment: Task Record Type ID: This value isn't valid for the user:

Comment: Ratan, If I hardcode it, this seems to be working fine. But i dont want to hardcode the recordtypeid

Comment: @chaith then clearly issue in `component.get("v.Task.recortypeid")` it is giving wrong value.

Comment: @chaith `v.Task` what is this contain?

Comment: seems like the object:object value is not populating

Comment: @chaith issue resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't 
"recordTypeId" : component.get("v.Task.recortypeid") 
Be 
"recordTypeId" : component.get("v.Task.recordtypeid")  
?  
Notice the d in recordtypeid in the last one.